# Optimizing copied code in Java, avoiding if clause and casting

Tags: java, enums

I have two classes:
`DocumentState` and `ElectronicDocumentState`.

They look like this:

```
public class DocumentState extends LabeledEnum {
    public static final DocumentState CREATED = new DocumentState("created");
    // ..... - 15 other statuses
}
```

`ElectronicDocumentState` also extends `LabeledEnum` and has its own statuses, some are common like created, other are unique.

Then I have plenty of methods in code that take `DocumentState` as a parameter or are returning `DocumentState` as result. Now they should work also with `ElectronicDocumentState`.

Also I have plenty places that do:

```
if (DocumentSate.CREATED.equals(doc.getState()) || DocumentState.DELETED.equals(doc.getState())) {
    //do something with document
}
```

I want to avoid 'if' and avoid creating new methods for `ElectronicDocumentState` as more state can appear in future.

How would you do that ?

So using the below example, how would you refactor it so it could work with `DocumentState` and `ElectronicDocumentState`? I have plenty of such methods that now should also work with `ElectronicDocumentState`. Someone asks us to mix electronicDocuments with documents in business logic:

```
private DocumentState getDocumentStateForDetails(Document doc, DocumentState sourceState) {

    if (DocumentState.CREATED.equals(doc.getDocumentState())) {
        if (sourceState.equals(DocumentState.CREATED)) {
            return DocumentState.CREATED;
        } else {
            return DocumentState.BLOCKED;
        }
    } else {
        return sourceState.getDocumentState();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you used proper enums, you'd be able to use a `switch`. You can add fields and methods to enum values, just like with regular classes.

Comment: How is that 'really' different from if? But if the methods called are defined in LabeledEnum, you can just call that method via `LabeledEnum` and not cast to the implementation class

Comment: Well, you can potentially add methods to the enum value for `isFoo`, `isBar` etc, the things currently checked via the ifs. Somehow you've got to check something.

Comment: Or you could put all the checks in some method like `getStatus()` and then `int status = getStatus()` and with the return result (an int preferably) you can just do `if(status == 1)`

Comment: Domain modeling is an involved topic, full of rules to follow and exceptions to every rule.  You are asking two separate questions here (one how to model two separate enums and how to avoid ifs in ones code base related to the enums).  I suggest breaking this question into two stackoverflow questions and then giving a concrete and fairly complete example that can be the focus of the question.

Comment: I am thinking about deleting ElectronicDocumentState from the project and leaving only DocumentState that would have mixed statuses for all kind of document.

Comment: Can you use enums instead? What methods are on `LabeledEnum` (which is poorly named btw, since it can not be an actual `enum`)

Comment: @user1308908 that is quite possibly a good idea.. it is difficult to be sure without understanding your domain.. however a good test is, does removing one of them allow you to express what you need more simply that it did with them both.

Comment: Other patterns that may help you are variations of callbacks;  such as the command/listener patterns and the more functional approach of passing operations into the enum which are only invoked if the enum is of specific state.  They limit the scattering effect of having ifs everywhere in the code base.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worrying about further extension of your state model, I'd suggest you to think about using inheritance instead of if/switch and instanceof by splitting the document class to Value and State, for instance. If you have the same set of available actions for any state of document, just use classical State pattern, otherwise, each State may have its own set of available actions:

```
public class Document {

    public static CreatedDocument<Document> create(String author) {
        return new CreatedDocument<>(new Document(author));
    }

    private String author;
    //...

    private Document(String author) {
        //...
    }
}

public class ElectronicDocument extends Document {

    public static CreatedElectronicDocument create(String author, String url) {
        return new CreatedElectronicDocument(author, url);
    }

    private String url;
    //...

    public ElectronicDocument(String author, String url) {
        //...
    }
    //...
}

public interface DocumentState<T extends Document> {

    T getDocument();

    char getCode(); // might be needed for something like logging?
}

public abstract class AbstractDocumentState<T extends Document> implements DocumentState<T> {

    protected final T document;

    protected AbstractDocumentState(T document) {
        this.document = document;
    }

    @Override
    public T getDocument() {
        return document;
    }
}

public class CreatedDocument<T extends Document> extends AbstractDocumentState<T> {

    public CreatedDocument(T document) {
        super(document);
    }

    @Override
    public char getCode() {
        return 'C';
    }

    public DocumentState<T> delete() {
        return new DeletedDocument<>(document);
    }
}

public class CreatedElectronicDocument extends CreatedDocument<ElectronicDocument> {

    public CreatedElectronicDocument(String author, String url) {
        super(new ElectronicDocument(author, url));
    }

    public DownloadElectronicDocument download() {
        return new DownloadElectronicDocument(document);
    }
}

public class DownloadElectronicDocument extends AbstractDocumentState<ElectronicDocument> {

    public DownloadElectronicDocument(ElectronicDocument document) {
        super(document);
        // DO DOWNLOAD HERE
    }

    @Override
    public char getCode() {
        return 'L';
    }

    public DocumentState<ElectronicDocument> delete() {
        return new DeletedDocument<>(document);
    }
}

public class DeletedDocument<T extends Document> extends AbstractDocumentState<T> {

    public DeletedDocument(T document) {
        super(document);
        // DO DELETE HERE
    }

    @Override
    public char getCode() {
        return 'D';
    }
}
```

Not sure you need getCode() now, when you use inheritance. BTW, switch works faster than a set of if/else if.

If you'd like to stay with your enum classes, why wouldn't to extract common states to a super class?

```
public class CommonDocumentState extends LabeledEnum {
    public static final CommonDocumentState CREATED = new CommonDocumentState ("created");
    ..... - n other statuses
}

public class DocumentState extends CommonDocumentState {
    ..... - m other statuses
}

public class ElectronicDocumentState extends CommonDocumentState {
    ..... - k other statuses
}
```

That's the only way to have such generic rules like

```
if (DocumentSate.CREATED.equals(doc.getState()) || DocumentState.DELETED.equals(doc.getState())) {
    //do something with document
}
```

be working for both DocumentState and ElectronicDocumentState.

Comment: This answer would be stronger if it also included when to not use inheritance for modeling;  it does have its own problems with extension.

Answer (score 0):

There are not enough information about your domain to provide a final answer, but I have some suggestions:

1. it seems that both DocumentState and ElectronicDocumentState inherit from LabeledEnum; if you want to manage both of them in your methods you can make ElectronicDocumentState inherit from DocumentState of it's feasibile merge the two classes. This will allow to pass ElectronicDocumentState or DocumentState in your methods and perhaps solve your second question.
2. if you want to avoid the if you can build a list of allowed method and check against the list, something like:

L

```
public class YourClass {

List<DocumentSate> allowedStates=//init here or in constructor
....
public void yourMethod(....) {
  if (allowedStates.contains(doc.getState())) {
     //do something
  }
 }
```

`allowedStates` may be factored out in separate class if it is a common case. If you find the refactoring feasible, may be you can check if you are dealing with a [finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) and implement it (with the help of some [exisiting libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875317/recommended-fsm-finite-state-machine-library-for-java)).